# Unable to access MySQL from C# application because of Exception: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Tags: c#, php, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I am making a simple application and while connecting it to the MySQL Database I have running using WAMP Server, it is throwing an exception and can't connect.

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have tried changing the users, database names but still nothing works.

The string I am using for establishing the connection is

```
string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=testdb;Uid=root;Pwd=root1234;";
```

Please Help. I have a project due on Monday morning.

Comment: Can you access your server via Console?

Comment: Unless you changed something on WAMPServer the only user/pass in MYSQL is the default `root` with no password

Comment: I hadn't changed it earlier. The exception was same except the part "Using password:NO"

Comment: I am able to access the database using phpmyadmin. I tried all the accounts I had created. All were accessible by phpmyadmin and the privileges were also set to global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now.
The problem was I had installed MySQL Community version and also had MySQL in WAMP so very probably they both were causing conflicts.
I uninstalled both and reinstalled WAMP. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user in MySql

```
 CREATE USER 'username'@'servername' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or using phpmyadmin select database and create a new user or update password

If you are using wamp xamp like packs be carefull becouse if you change root password phpmyadmin would be break;

i suggest create a new user and give root previlliges to that user 
and NEVER USE root user in production

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it with the following way:

```
        string servidor = "127.0.0.1";
        string puerto = "3308";
        string usuario = "root";
        string clave = "";
        string basededatos = "db01";

        string CadenaDeConexion = "Database=" + basededatos + "; DataSource=" + servidor + "; Port=" + puerto + "; User ID=" + usuario + "; Password=" + clave;
        MySqlConnection MiConexion = new MySqlConnection(CadenaDeConexion);
```